# Composite component with h:form weird rendering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, wildfly

Composite components with an `h:form` render in a weird way. This is the JSF markup I'm using:

```
<div id="modals">
  <div id="modal1">
    <custom:mycomp />
  </div>
  <div id="modal2">
    <custom:mycomp />
  </div>
  <div id="modal3">
    <custom:mycomp />
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, instead of rendering each composite component inside its respective `div`, the source of the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="modals">
  <div id="modal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog"><!-- My rendered component --></div>        
    <div id="modal2">
      <div class="modal-dialog"><!-- My rendered component --></div> 
      <div id="modal3">
        <div class="modal-dialog"><!-- My rendered component --></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

They are being rendered inside each other, not on the same level. I found out that removing the `h:form` inside my composite component fixes the issue, but I need it to trigger some actions. The composite component renders the markup for a **Twitter Bootstrap** modal:

```
<cc:interface></cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><!-- HEADER --></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h:form>
        <!-- My form. Removing this form renders the HTML correctly but I need it to invoke some actions here -->
      </h:form>
    </div>
  </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

I'm using **Wildfly 8.0.0 Final**. Is there something I'm missing or is this a bug in the JSF implementation? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it appears to be a bug in the implementation. Changed to **Wildfly 8.1.0-CR2** and is now working fine.